# node js for XMPP protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, xmppframework, xmlnode

I want to develop an instant messaging for mobile application, like **whatsapp**, with **nodejs** as my backend. I have gone through **XMPP** protocols and read **xmpp.org** documentation as well.

I referred to this **[link](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp/blob/master/README.markdown)** and I am able to build some of the basic **XMPP** functionality  like creating and messaging users. But I am still unable to implement the complete functionality of **XMPP** in **nodejs**.

So: are there any node js libaries available to build the complete functionality of xmpp protocol, such as **asmack**?  Alternatively, how do I send calls to **XMPP** server via **XML**?

Comment: Why do you need nodejs if you already have XMPP server? What is node js job here? XMPP is just XML message exchange protocol, do you want to implement XMPP server in node or client? or a middle layer? Here is a nodejs XMPP library to communicate with XMPP server or creating a server in nodejs
https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp

Comment: yes, The nodejs application will act as like a middle layer, That application will receive requests from mobile via API calls. The XMPP operations will be performed in that nodejs application and then results will be sent back to the mobile from the nodejs. Can you please suggest me, Is it possible to do by this way. Or If any other suggestions are acceptable..

Answer (score 1):

XMPP is the standard for messaging. But it is not clear how Node will help you better than an established library on another platform. Node does make it a breeze to do scalable web socket apps, which work a lot better using JSON instead of XML though. So perhaps what you want to do is build a web socket IM application in Node and also implement an XMPP interface.

- For web socket and REST implementation: http://express-io.org
- For XMPP interface to the Express.io application: https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp